# Alphabetical organization of sublists in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, sublist

I have a list that consists of contacts. For example:

```
phones = [['Jerry', '(212) 745-3837'],['Elliot', '(212) 843-2724']]
```

I need to sort it alphabetically so that it is:

```
[['Elliot', '(212) 843-2724'],['Jerry', '(212) 745-3837']]
```

I'm a beginner so simple answers are appreciated! Thanks so much.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Comment: Make use of sorted() function: `print(sorted(phones))`